# Is there way to use SVG element inside Adobe XD plugin Dialog?

Tags: adobe-xd

I'm trying to import a SVG using `<img/>`. Seems like it's not working. Any workaround for this issue?
`<img src="./assets/icon.svg" alt="Icon">`.

Answer (score 1):

There’s not currently a direct workaround for this. Lack of SVG support in the UI APIs is noted as a [known issue](https://adobexdplatform.com/plugin-docs/known-issues.html#user-interface) in the docs.

For now, you’ll need to use another image format.